# ANOVA for feature selection

Tags: r, anova

I'm trying to perform feature selection with *ANOVA* in R. CUrrently I have a large matrix (named *expressionMarix*) where my expression profiles are stored and a factor (named Labels) where 4 types of disease are represented.
*expressionMatrix* looks like this:

```
           1007_s_at    1053_at     117_at    121_at   1255_g_at
GSM1304852  2.394537 0.10510845 -0.4597124 0.9333566 -0.23991384
GSM1304853  2.275184 0.06160802 -0.5231035 1.1318090  0.10112324
GSM1304854  2.161163 0.34217618 -0.4436059 0.9975700 -0.04087979
GSM1304855  1.964183 0.35939157 -0.6370277 1.0079778 -0.21851374
GSM1304856  2.132253 0.22356958 -0.3511470 0.9720455 -0.29917857
```

Where the columns are genes and the rows are samples.

Is there a package that allows me to select relevant columns using ANOVA?
My current code looks like this:

```
modelAnova <- aov(expressionMatrix ~ Labels)
sumAnova <- summary(modelAnova)
pValList <- list()
i = 1
while(i < dim(Mstriat)[1]){
  print(i)
  pValList[i] <- sumAnova[[i]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]
  i <- i+1
}
keepers<-which(cValList<0.05)
```

But the for loop is really time consuming. Is there a more efficient method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without having a `dput(expressionMarix)` and `dput(Labels)` outputs, it's a bit hard to give the perfect answer, however, I faced the same problem with other models, and it helped a lot the `broom::tidy()` function. The idea is to transform the model in a `data.frame`, then subset only the rows with the wanted `p.value`, that is a column now:

```
library(broom)
# this is going to put in a data.frame the output of the model
inline <- tidy(modelAnova)

# here you filter the p.value <= 0.05
inline[!is.na(inline$p.value <= 0.05),]
```